# findByType function not finding property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm writing tests for components I have main component Icon

```
const Icon: React.FC<IIconPropTypes> = ({ size, color, icon, onClick, blockEvents }) => (
  <IconWrapper onClick={onClick} blockEvents={blockEvents}>
    <IconSvg color={color} hasClick={!!onClick} width={size}>
      <path d={ICONS_PATH[icon]} />
    </IconSvg>
  </IconWrapper>
);
```

and IconSvg which I am testing

```
const IconSvg = styled.svg<IIconSvgProps>`
  cursor: ${(props) => (props.hasClick ? 'pointer' : 'default')};
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: ${(props) => (props.width ? `${props.width}px` : '100%')};
  path {
    fill: ${(props) => (props.color ? props.color : '#edcd7d')};
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
`;
```

This is how my test looks like

```
it('matches snapshot and renders without color prop', () => {
    const [hasClick, width] = [true, 100];
    const component = renderer.create(<IconSvg hasClick={hasClick} width={width}/>);
    const tree = component.toJSON() as ReactTestRendererJSON;
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(component.root.findByType('path')).toHaveStyleRule('fill', '#edcd7d');
  })
```

But findByType cannot find the path, and therefore the fill property, can anyone know what the error is and how to reach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing your `IconSvg` component here:

```
let component = renderer.create(<IconSvg hasClick={hasClick} width={width}/>);
```

According to your code `IconSvg` is just a styled `svg`. You need to test `Icon` component which has a `path` element in it:

```
let component = renderer.create(<Icon size={} color={} icon={} onClick={} blockEvents={} } />);
```